# Get a stream of a remote camera

Tags: camera, stream, webrtc

I need to start a live stream in a remote computer connected to a webcam,
then connect to that remote ip address and see the live stream, like a security webcam more or less.
On my client i want to be able to see the stream in my browser.

What I've tried so far:

- VLC on the remote pc: I start the stream (MMS, HTTP or RSTP) and then I encapsulate the stream as object in a html page.
  This works, but I have a high latency and not all the browsers support x-vlc-plugin.
- WebRTC. This seemed to me the best solution. Direct stream, very low latency.
  I tried all the solutions I found in internet, that also integrate node.js. I tried also to build some code myself but the problem is that:
- I start the stream on the "server", the remote pc.
- When i go to the client, I type in the browser the ip address and port of the remote PC. In theory I should be able to see the REMOTE stream, but instead the browser asks for permission to use my LOCAL camera!

Do you have some hints or solutions about? What am I doing wrong?
Last project I tried:

https://github.com/xat/webcam-binaryjs-demo

In this project:

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple-relay/
the developer uses a relay of the stream.
Buttons work but I don't know how to use this, that is how to catch the relay and display it on the client.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: there is no way to skip browser asks

Comment: don't want to skip browser question. But the browser asks to use my LOCAL camera. I don't want that. I only want to be able to see the REMOTE stream.

Answer (score 1):

webRTC has three common API

**getUserMedia**  : for communication and streaming between camera/mic with browser (request permission for access to camera/mic)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

**RTCDataChannel**  : data channel for send/receive any type of data on connection
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel

**RTCPeerConnection** : for creating peer-to-peer connection
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection

you don't need getUserMedia

find getUserMedia() , this method send access request for camera and microphone to user , you can set both boolean false , or remove it carefully

```
navigator.getUserMedia({
    video:false,
    audio:true,
},function(mediaStream){...
```

Comment: You'll also need to use offerToReceiveVideo when doing createOffer, since you're not sending media.  I presume you're running something (node) that lets you exchange the offer/answer and candidates without needing an external server.